# Why when I increase SSL certificate security on my mac am I unable to use the app store (preflight error)?

Tags: macos, security, keychain, ssl

Given the recent OSX issues with certificates and SSL, I want to increase the security of the certificate validation in general.

I came across a setting in the keychain that has a selection between best attempt and require if certificate indicates.  The selection of always validate is greyed out.

[image]

When I do this, I [get an error when using the app store](https://discussions.apple.com/message/23454677#23454677) "Unable to verify the preflight file". reverting to "best effort" seems to fix the issue.

How can I increase the security of my SSL / PKI certificate validation without breaking functionality of other apps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known bug in the App Store. Apple needs to fix it.

> The only problem with forcing a check of revoked certificates is that
>   Apple has a flaw in how it validates Mac App Store updates. With the
>   option selected as shown in the figure below, you may be unable to
>   perform updates through the App Store program. To fix that, launch
>   Keychain Access, change the preferences to Best Attempt, update your
>   apps, and then reset to the stricter setting. This is something Apple
>   should clearly fix, since all the components of this situation are
>   under its control.

http://www.macworld.com/article/1162472/keep_your_mac_safe_from_web_security_flaws.html